# Why does router-link work in App.vue but gives me "Failed to resolve component: router-link" in a component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router4

I'm trying to set up vue-router; in my top-level App.vue, I have

```
<template>
  <div>
  App.vue: hello,
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    <hr/>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

and it works fine.

I'd like to include these links in a component, but that gives me an error

```
"Failed to resolve component: router-link"
```

Any pointers to where I should look for an answer? I've read the API documentation but it doesn't make any reference to any file or import needed in my component file. TIA

Comment: The `router-*` components are globally registered by the Vue Router plugin. Where have you installed the plugin? Can you share a link to a reproduction?